# python date.min does not convert back. Why?

Tags: python, sqlite

Consider this code:

```
datestring = date.min.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
date = datetime.strptime(datestring,"%d-%m-%Y")
```

This raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/Dev/foo.py", line 37, in <module>
    datestring = date.min.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") ValueError: year=1 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900
```

Why is the min date not 1900 then???

I'm using storing date.min in the **init** of a class as to set it to an empty date sortof. When I persist this to the sqlite database, I do not have a Null date this way.

I do this because when I read back an empty date from the db, it raises an error in dbapi2.py in the convertdate function

How do you guys solve this?

Comment: print the contents of datestring to see the correct format.

Comment: You'll be happy to know that you can go back to year 1000 (but not any lower) with python 3.2. Expect year 1 in python 4... ;)

Comment: Actually, AJ, it's the "datestring = date.min.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")" statement that gives the error, so, you cannot even print datestring.

Comment: @sixfeetsix: But what is purpose of date.min then? You would get the same error would you not?

Comment: Yes absolutely; I was being sarcastic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not the problem with `date.min` or `datetime` module, problem is due to platform-specific weirdnesses in implementations of `strftime`

see http://bugs.python.org/issue1777412

A work around would be to set a `date_min > 1900` or just use a hand crafted string for your default date value

Comment: I ended up using a variable MINDATE = date(1900,1,1) I find it ridiculous

Answer (score 4):

You could stick the "ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM-DD":

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime
>>> date_str = date.min.isoformat()
>>> print date_str
0001-01-01
>>> date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str,"%Y-%m-%d")
>>> print date_obj
0001-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: very nice! This perfectly covers my need. Thanks!